# Get Oracle command with parameters filled in

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, oracle-enterprise-manager

The parameterized OracleCommand I build in my C# code throws an exception when I run:

```
OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

When I run the same command in Oracle Enterprise Manager Console by taking the parameters values and filling them in, the command executes as expected.

My question is: Is there a way to see the actual OracleCommand being executed with parameters filled in when debugging in Visual Studio?

I've tried putting a breakpoint on the line above but `command.CommandText` is still the parameterized command.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd edit your question and A) include more of the code, such as everything that leads up to executing the above statement including the initialization of the `command` variable, and B) some detailed information about the exception which is being thrown. I don't know about the other folks who often handle Oracle-related questions, but right now my crystal ball is in the shop, they can't get parts, don't know when it'll be fixed, yada-yada - you know the drill... Thanks.

Comment: My question is NOT what's wrong with my code... my question is how can I get the actual command(with parameter values filled in) being executed by oracle.. therefore how i build my command shouldn't be relevant